# Name for having a background of the main element

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background

I am totally new to illustrator and I am trying to make myself a logo. Something neat I found online was a trick where you used the same image in the foreground in another color as the background. This trick is used here :

[image]

Is there a name to this technique? I am trying to find out how to achieve this effect but don't know where to concentrate my search on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find a name for this.

It's merely -- **Duplicate, Scale, Change Color**.